# How could I reach a specific tag while using DOM?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, intellij-idea, dom

Please show me how to reach "autovehicul" as result, while language is english and its sibling is car. Thank you.
If language english is selected and car is selected, in a web service, my answer must be autovehicul, if romanian language exists.

How can you parse that xml to reach an answer like that. I have an issue with targeting a specific node. Condition - Nodelist - Iterate -  Condition -  Node - get Tag. Then, i have to establish the node of autovehicul content, and get the required result.

```
<Word>
    <equivalent>
        <language>english</language>
        <word-translate>car</word-translate>
    </equivalent>

    <equivalent>
        <language>romanian</language>
        <word-translate>autovehicul</word-translate>
    </equivalent>
</Word>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var parser, xmlDoc;
var text = "<Word> <equivalent><language>english</language><word-translate>car</word-translate></equivalent>" +
"<equivalent><language>romanian</language><word-translate>autovehicul</word-translate></equivalent></Word>";

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("word-translate")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or you can try XPath for an easier access.

Comment: My problem is how to reach a node. I have a target a simple tag. You use NodeList, iterate through it, put a condition (if language exists) then Node class to get the targeted tag. XPath will never work with tags. If I could modify the .xml, life will be easier. They say, just tags. It has to be simple. <word>
        <romanian>autovehicul</romanian>
        <english>car</english>
        <spanish>coche</spanish>
        <italian>auto</italian>
        <swedish>bil</swedish>
        <greek>αυτοκίνητο</greek>
    </word>   Get me auto from italian language. That's all I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question, but I think you might looking for something like this: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

Comment: If language english is selected and car is selected, in a web service, my answer must be autovehicul.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I can't add more question if this is not solved.
DOM wasn't a very good idea. IT works but you need hardcoding, witch doesn't help me a lot. Instead I've dropped DOM and used another way. Unfortunately I can't show you the code, because it was part of school assignment and we have an agreement to obey.
All I can say is you can analyze your document and parsing it using SAX or StAX.
The people trying to help me like ms. Purta, offered me an answer that uses ID. Thank you for you time. I've tried to select your answer as a good one, but I must be at 15 level...  master potion level ...to have a say at my own post. :D
I can't ask more questions, not for a while until these are solved somehow. The problem is the school regulation. They are the mean ones.

```
NodeList wordNode = document.getElementsByTagName(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < wordNode.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = wordNode.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType()== Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            Element eElement = (Element) node;
            String result ="romanian";
            switch (result) {
                case "english" -> result = eElement.getElementsByTagName("english").item(0).getTextContent();
                case "romanian" -> result = eElement.getElementsByTagName("romanian").item(0).getTextContent();
                case "spanish" -> result = eElement.getElementsByTagName("spanish").item(0).getTextContent();
                case "italian" -> result = eElement.getElementsByTagName("italian").item(0).getTextContent();
                case "swedish" -> result = eElement.getElementsByTagName("swedish").item(0).getTextContent();
                case "greek" -> result = eElement.getElementsByTagName("greek").item(0).getTextContent();
            }
            return result;
        }
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            Element sElement = (Element) node;
            String source = "english";
            switch (source){
                case "english" -> source = sElement.getParentNode().getNodeName();
                case "romanian" -> source = sElement.getParentNode().getNodeName();
                case "spanish" -> source = sElement.getParentNode().getNodeName();
                case "italian" -> source = sElement.getParentNode().getNodeName();
                case "swedish" -> source = sElement.getParentNode().getNodeName();
                case "greek" -> source = sElement.getParentNode().getNodeName();
            }
            return source;
        }
```

}
return null;

The ID was not a solution but it works. Also XPath works.
That is all!